# Ajax call fail when I can trying to pass the special characters as data

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-mobile

This is the code I am using to add a comment using Ajax call.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/> 
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-    1.1.0-rc.1.min.css" />        
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova-1.5.0.js">
   </script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/global.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<script>
    var msgId = window.localStorage.getItem("clickedId");

    processLogInData = function(){
                var comment = ($("#comment").val());
                temp =  'messageId=' + msgId +'&';
                temp += 'uniqueId=' + device.uuid + '&';
                temp += 'comments=' + comment;  
                var s= global1 +"rest/Comment/createCommentBO?"+temp;

                $.ajax({
                    url:global1 +"rest/Comment/createCommentBO?",
                    data: temp,
                    dataType: 'xml',
                    timeout: 10000,
                    async: false,
                    cache: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function(data){
                        if($(data).find("isException").text() == "false")
                        {
                            //alert('No Exceptions found');
                                                                onTrue();

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            onFalse();
                        }
                    },
                    error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown) {
                              //  alert("Error status :"+textStatus);
                              //  alert("Error type :"+errorThrown);
                                alert("Error message :"+XMLHttpRequest.responseXML);
                                $("#messagelist").append( XMLHttpRequest.responseXML);
                                                                       } 
                     });
              }
                     function onTrue(){
                                location.replace("comments.html");
                                  }   
                    function onFalse()
                              {
                                  console.log("onFalse Method");
                                  alert("Unable to create Comment!");
                                  }
                    function cancel(){
                        location.replace("comments.html");
                    }
</script>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="a">
         <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
           <img src="images/logo_header.png" alt="Orange"/>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
           <form method="post" name="login" data-ajax="false">
           <label for="textarea"><h3><u>Add Comment</u> : </h3></label>
           <textarea cols="15" rows="15" name="textarea" id="comment"></textarea>
           </form>
           <div>
<div class="ui-block-a"><button type="submit" data-theme="d" onclick="cancel();" data-mini="true" data-icon="delete">Cancel</button></div>
<div class="ui-block-b"><button type="submit" data-theme="a" onclick="processLogInData();" data-mini="true" data-icon="check" >Submit</button></div>
     </div>
           </div>
          </div> 
</body>
```

When I enter special character as content as pass it to Ajax call I am getting an error :( Ajax call works fine with out any special characters...
Is there any way to encode the data before passing it to ajax call???Please help me on this...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

(1.)Either you should put your data into a form and serialize it and then send to the server
(2.)Second way is you can use the js inbuilt function encodeURIComponent().